# Unable to receive POST data using a class defined in a class library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-class-library

I have two projects: one is a .NET Core class library, the other is a .NET Core minimal web API.

`SomeClassLibrary.csproj`

```
// SomeClass.cs
namespace SomeClassLibrary.Some.Arbitrary.Namespace 
{
  public class SomeClass 
  {
    public SomeClass() {}
    public SomeSubClass? subClassObject {get; set;}
  }
  public class SomeSubClass 
  {
    public SomeSubClass() {}
    public string? id {get; set;}
  }
}
```

`SomeMinimalWebAPI.csproj`

```
// Program.cs
using SomeClassLibrary.Some.Arbitrary.Namespace;

... 

app.MapPost("/endpoint", ([FromBody] SomeClass someClassObject) => 
  {
    // do stuff with someClassObject
    return "OK";
  });

...
```

If I POST from Postman, for example, with JSON like so:

```
{
  "subClassObject" : 
  {
    "id" : "some value"
  }
}
```

I get a `200` status code, but no `OK` in the response body as expected.

I have tested that using `[FromBody] SomeClass someClassObject` works just fine when referenced in the same solution, but referenced from a class library as I have demonstrated here makes it seem like `MapPost` is hanging for some reason. I get no error codes. And to reiterate, I get a `200` in Postman, but no `OK` in the response body. Further, if I configure the Postman POST request with invalid JSON, I *do* receive an error response telling `Required parameter "SomeClass someClassObject" was not provided from body`.

I can even new up a `SomeClass` object, including its nested `SomeSubClass` object, and use it in the code. But as soon as I try to pass it as a parameter to be deserialized `FromBody`, it hangs with zero indication as to what is happening.

Everything seems to be referenced correctly, as my `using` statements referencing `SomeClassLibrary.Some.Arbitrary.Namespace` grant me access to the controllers and models and stuff I have written in the class library. I have rebuilt, cleaned, unloaded, reloaded everything multiple times.

A datapoint that may or may not matter: my class library depends on `Newtonsoft.Json` to do work on serializing/deserializing my objects. I can't see why I would need to reference that in my web API since it's calling outside of itself to do all of that work, and it's not throwing any errors.

I am truly at a loss as to why I can't grab this object `FromBody` *specifically* when referencing its class from a class library. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And further clarification can of course be provided.

EDIT

For further clarification, I am noticing some extremely bizarre behavior depending on what JSON I feed the POST endpoint.

```
{
  "id" : "some value"
}
```

returns `OK` in the response body.

but

```
{
  "subClassObject" : 
  {
    "id" : "some value" 
  }
}
```

still returns nothing.

I cannot stress enough that using the second JSON shape *DOES WORK* in the project that references `SomeClass` within the same solution exactly as intended.

Comment: what exactly are you looking for, Can you please ask in one line? your question is very lengthy

Comment: @viveknuna In short, the data retrieved `FromPost` in the `MapPost` function of my web API cannot be mapped to an object that I have defined in a separate class library. The request hangs, but gives me a `200` status with no response body.

Comment: this is your equivalent class to your json `public class Root
    {
        public SubClassObject subClassObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubClassObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: This is all an example. As I stated, I have used this *exact class* this *exact way* but referenced from within the same solution, and it worked. For some reason, when I reference this class from *outside* of the web API project, it doesn't work. Does that make sense?